# Update Random value only on page refresh

Tags: google-sheets

I am using `=RANDBETWEEN(1,100)`function to generate a two digit random integer. But I want these values to refresh only on the page refresh, whereas currently they are changing whenever any cell is edited.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to resort to Google Apps Script for this:

```
function onOpen()
{
  var cell = "Sheet1!A1";
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cell).setValue(
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 99));
}
```

Ensure that you run the script manually first to go through the authorisation process.